# Do laptop's power bricks provide constant voltage?

Tags: power-supply, dc

Some laptop power bricks say they provide 18V or 24V. I know that these values aren't applied as constant voltages to the laptop's battery because they must receive a much more complex power signal for optimal charging.

I don't know if the battery charging signal is calculated at the external power brick or by some component inside the laptop.

Should I expect a constant voltage from an external power brick?

Comment: Battery charging is in the laptop; there will be a buck/boost converter or current limiting transistor in the laptop itself.

Answer (score 7):

So far as I know, power supply "bricks" for laptop/notebook computers are not really "chargers" in that they do not attempt to impose a suitable regime for charging a bettery of specific chemistry according to it's current measured state. They are simply power supplies.

Any charging circuitry is, I believe, usually incorporated within the computer housing the battery.

The name "charger" is often a misnomer.

You can therefore expect these power "bricks" to provide a near-constant voltage when connected to a load that draws a current within the range provided for by the designers of the system.

If the load is too small or too high, the voltage may deviate from the stated value considerably.

Answer (score 4):

A definitive answer is not possible without specifying "this particular model number of laptop power supply". However, generalizations can be made:

A **DC output** power adapter provides *approximately* the nominal voltage specified on it, with some ripple. The conditioning of this power to the specifics needed for charging the batteries, is done by a battery management circuit within the laptop, in some cases within the battery itself.

This is required so that different laptops, with batteries of varying age (and therefore different ideal charging parameters) or even of differing nominal charge capacity, can work with a mass-produced "power brick", without requiring any standardized communication to modify the power brick's behavior.

Some laptop chargers do exist with a data channel, a means of communicating from the laptop back to the power brick. However, given that such communication does not provide any notable advantage to the power conversion circuit, it seems likely that the communication is of use primarily to validate that a power brick is an officially approved one from the brand. Anything to prevent off-brand OEMs from selling the customer something which works just as good at half the price - I'm sure we all know some of the brands that would do such a thing.

An **AC output** power brick, not so common in recent products, essentially consists of a step-down transformer and some protection circuitry. These supplies provide a known ratio of the mains voltage, at mains-frequency, to the laptop. Thus voltage varies with line voltage.

Such AC power bricks require rectification and power conditioning to be done within the laptop, hence even less value to a communication path back to the "power brick".

Comment: Validating that a power supply is the proper manufacturer-recommended model may be an effort to capture the business of customers needing replacement units, but it may also stem from a desire to avoid having battery-charge monitoring get confused by a power supply that varies under load.  As for AC-output power bricks, those are becoming increasingly less common than other sorts because the only practical way to make one is to use a 60Hz transformer, and it it's hard to make such transformers be both cheap and efficient.

Comment: ... or 50 Hz, for some parts of the world, like mine :-) Yup, I agree, AC power bricks are getting extremely rare... again excepting in certain economies.